# Virmire Bomb Site Rescue - Bugged?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect

I'm in the middle of the Virmire Assault quest.  During the battle, I chose to go help my people at the bomb site.  After clearing out the enemies, the game seems stalled now.

I can wander between the bomb site and the Breeding Trench to the west, but I can't take the elevator up from the Breeding Trench, and no other exits from the bomb site are available.  Nothing in the bomb site seems available for interaction, and I can't find anything to kill.

Is my game bugged at this point?

I'm going to try reloading and playing through here again, to see if the problem recurs.  I just wanted to check to see if this is a known bug and if there might be some workarounds (other than save/reload) I could use if it happens again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the re-load and playing through again, I think I figured it out.  There was a radio comm from an NPC that was supposed to precede a cutscene.  I'd accidentally cut that comm short by interacting with one of the NPCs in my shore party.  That must have broken the intended cutscene sequence.

After the reload and allowing the comm to proceed normally, everything played out fine.